# Pluriels des syntagmes nominaux composés et distribués

Tags: pluriel, noms

Ma fille de trois ans adore les chevaux, elle en parle à longueur de journée et a trois petites figurines de plastique qu'elle  appelle *bébé-cheval*, *maman-cheval* et *papa-cheval*. Ce matin sa tournure m'a interloqué :

> C'est mon papa et ma maman cheval

Je m'interroge donc sur le pluriel des syntagmes nominaux composés et  distribués.

Je sais que l'intitulé de ma question est confus, mais si j'étais capable de formuler exactement le problème en termes grammaticaux conventionnels, je n'aurais qu'à googler la réponse. Ne vous gênez pas pour l'éditer.

J'entends par syntagme nominal composé des expressions comme *femme chat*, *homme enfant*, *sœurs jumelles*, *enfant-roi*…

où le deuxième nom du groupe vient modifier le premier, un peu à la manière d'un adjectif.

Par distribué, j'entends le cas ou un mot se rapporte à deux autres précédents – singuliers– et prend en conséquence le pluriel : « un homme et une femme amoureux », « un chien et un chat mouillés »…

À l'oreille je dirais comme ma fille « un papa et une maman cheval ».

1. Doit-on dire « un papa et une maman chevaux » ? Pourquoi ?
2. Quelle que soit la réponse, quels termes ou formulation aurais-je dû utiliser pour pouvoir trouver la réponse moi-même dans le Grevisse ou sur Google  ?

Comment: Tant qu`à tout accorder, pourquoi pas bébé-poulain et maman-jument ?

Answer (score 9):

Dans les deux phrases :

> un homme et une femme amoureux;
>   un chien et un chat mouillés...

amoureux et mouillés sont des adjectifs et s'accordent en nombre.

par contre dans la phrase :

> c'est mon papa et ma maman cheval

cheval représente une espèce et ne s'accorde pas.

Comment: Si on suit cette logique, vous diriez donc des *papas cheval, *des enfants roi, des *femmes chat  ? Ça me parait bizarre.

Comment: @JoBedard On n'accorde pas *femme chat* au féminin, je ne vois pas pourquoi il serait accordé au pluriel...

Comment: @karen justement, pourquoi on n'accorde pas, non plus,ce genre de mot au féminin ? C'est la même question, essentiellement.

Answer (score 1):

C'est une tournure spécifique de la petite enfance.

"Maman lapin", "papa chien", "l'enfant mouton", "le bébé vache"...

L'enfant a une empathie naturelle pour les animaux, et tend à projeter ce qu'il connaît bien, et ce qui est le centre de son affectivité, sa structure familiale, sur le monde qui l'entoure.

Il le fait aussi sur les objets. "C'est le bébé ciseau" = il est plus petit que les autres.
Regarde maman, le ciseau il a une bouche, et des yeux. Il est content, tu vois, le ciseau.

Il personnifie les objets, les dotant d'une âme et de sentiments. C'est la pensée magique dont parle beaucoup de livres de la psychologie du développement.

(Voir les nombreux livres qui en parlent, par exemple "Sophie Morgenstern, « La Pensée magique chez l'enfant »)

Dans la phrase "le bébé mouton" par exemple, ainsi que dans les autres exemples cités utilisant cette construction, "mouton" est traité comme un adjectif (mais invariable), comme on dirait "le bébé indien", "le bébé anglais".

L'enfant projette donc sa structure familiale, et imagine qu'il existe un "peuple mouton" qui vit à l'image de la "tribu" constituée par son noyau familial.

ça a plus à voir avec la psychologie infantile qu'avec les structures propres au français (on rencontre ce genre de constructions dans d'autres langues) mais il est vrai que la linguistique rencontre la psychologie, la psychologie individuelle, ainsi que la psychosociologie. Cette question aurait davantage sa place sur un forum de linguistique générale et/ou de psychologie (infantile), ou mieux encore, de psycholinguistique.